# UITableView cell returning nil property values

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if(indexPath.row==0)
    {
        static NSString *CellID = @"FlourishCustomCell";
        FlourishCustomCell *cell = (FlourishCustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellID];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[FlourishCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellID] autorelease];
            cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0.0, 292.0, 30);
        }

        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = 
        [[appDelegate.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        NSLog(@"DATE:%@", [sectionInfo name]); //Output: March 25

        cell.dateLabel.text=[sectionInfo name];
        NSLog(@"header cell:%@", cell.dateLabel.text); //Output:header cell:(null)

        return cell;
    }
    else {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"IdeaCustomCell";
        IdeaCustomCell *cell = (IdeaCustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[IdeaCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
            cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0.0, 292.0, 70);
        }

        [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:[self newIndexPathForIndexPath:indexPath]];
        return cell;
    }
}
```

The cells display and work fine for the `else` part (the `IdeaCustomCell`), but for some extremely frustrating reason, when I set the `dateLabel` of the `FlourishCell`, and then immediately try to access that value, I get a `null` value, even though I just set it! And the cell doesn't display on screen.

I tried overriding the setter method for dateLabel in the `FlourishCustomCell` class, and I put an NSLog statement there, but it never gets called for some reason.

I have absolutely no idea what could be causing this. I mean I'm allocating right then and there, but it's still giving me null. Any ideas?

Comment: Where do you initialize the Label? in code? from nib? can you post the code for your custom cells? I bet the dateLabel is null as well

Comment: It's just the default UITableViewCell subclass methods. I haven't touched it. I'm supposed to initialize the label?

Comment: Yes, UITableViewCell doesn't have a UILabel called dateLabel, so you need to initialize it

Comment: UITableViewCell doesn't have a dateLabel property. You must have created it in your subclass. That's what aryaxt is asking for, the declaration of dateLabel and it's initialization.

Comment: Oh actually the cell is set up in an IB file..so that takes care of the initialization..

Comment: hm...you are doing something wrong..How does your FlourishCustomCell know about the .xib? You are not loading any .xib file...

Comment: I set the files owner of the xib as FlourishCustomCell. I'm doing the same exact thing as I did with the IdeaCustomCell, which is set up in the same way, and for some reason that works just fine

Comment: do NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([cell class]));, I'm guessing it's gonna tell you that the class type is UITableViewCell, and not FlourishCustomCell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize the label

Solution 1: Initializing cell in code

```
@interface FlourishCustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILable * dateLabel;

@end

@implementation FlourishCustomCell
@synthesize dateLabel = _dateLabel;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
   if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])
   {
      _dateLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,300,50)];
      [self.contentView addSubview:_dateLabel]
   }

   return self; 
}

@end
```

Solution 2: Initializing cell from nib

```
@interface FlourishCustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILable * dateLabel;

@end

@implementation FlourishCustomCell
@synthesize dateLabel = _dateLabel;

- (id)init
{
self = [[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YOUR_NIB_NAME" owner:nil options:nil] 
         lastObject] 
        retain];

   return self;
}

@end
```

**EDIT**: oops, forgot to return self on init method, updated the answer

Comment: The dateLabel apparently is in a .xib file. But he isn't even loading a .xib

Comment: I think the solution he has would only work with storyBoard, storyboard automatically look for the cell with the correct identifier and initialize the appropriate cell

Comment: Yup that did it:) I followed your solution 2 and it worked. Thank you my friend!

Comment: Solution 2 didn't work for me.... but solution 1 worked, however, solution 1 ignores the xib so there's no point in using this solution..

Comment: Isn't awakeFromNib method is doing the initialization behavior for .xib custom cells?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem when using nibs, this worked for me

```
- (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
if (!cell) {
    NSString* nibFile = @"NibForCell";

    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: nibFile owner:nil options: nil];
    cell  = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex: 0];
}

cell.cellText.text = @"test";

return cell;
}
```

just make sure you set the reuse identifier in the nib's properties