# UITableViewCell not loading subviews from storyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I think something odd is happening here. I've got a prototype cell with a few labels as subviews, and using `viewWithTag` to try and find them to set their text. I've done it 3 other times in the same project so I'm lost at what could be wrong.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Result Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    UILabel *racerNameLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:5002153];
    //more labels ... 
    return cell;
}
```

If I put in a breakpoint, racerNameLabel is nil and the cell has no subviews:

```
(lldb) po [[cell contentView] subviews]
    (id) $5 = 0x08161da0 <__NSArrayI 0x8161da0>(

)
```

Here's a snippit of the Storyboard itself, showing the label subview should definitely be there. It also shows the cell identifier is correct.

```
<tableViewCell contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="blue" hidesAccessoryWhenEditing="NO" indentationLevel="1" indentationWidth="0.0" reuseIdentifier="Result Cell" rowHeight="80" id="hGh-MB-iBH">
        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="22" width="382" height="80"/>
        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
        <view key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="382" height="79"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
            <subviews>
                <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" tag="5002153" contentMode="left" text="Racer Name" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Sf6-ol-OLA">
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="166" id="iI1-0U-gN8"/>
                    </constraints>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                    <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                    <color key="highlightedColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                </label>
```

(note I set the tag as a stupid number in my frustration trying to get it working)

Comment: You'll probably find it a lot easier to work with if you create a subclass of `UITableViewCell` with `IBOutlet`s instead of using tag.

Comment: Try this [UITableViewCell allocation issue - cell is not nil][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865609/uitableview-cell-returning-nil-property-values

Comment: @MichaelKernahan made a cell subclass called `RaceResultCell`, linked up the label with `IBOutlet`, changed the bits in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to refer to `RaceResultCell`, `cell.racerNameLabel` outcomes as nil again.

Comment: @sunkehappy shouldn't it be initialising the labels behind the scenes when it parses the storyboard?

Comment: even after doing `cell.racerNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];` the `cell.racerNameLabel` is still nil :s

Comment: hmm. If it is off of your storyboard, then you do not (and should not) be alloc/init'ing your label. I realize you probably just did that trying to get something, anything to work. :S

Comment: :[ hours wasted, and it was simply because my ViewController's tableView outlet wasn't connected to the table. Weird it was still working when not a custom cell. And yes, the alloc/init'ing was a desperate attempt.

Comment: Ha you solved it! When you debug, you need to check cell' super view, the table view.

Answer (score 22):

If you are registering your custom UITableViewCell cell with the indetifier you entered in Inspector in Interface Builder, that might be the problem. I had the same issue and when I removed the lines that were registering the custom class in viewDidLoad, it worked.

Comment: Wow, this is the answer, and it makes no frickin sense!

Comment: Who would have thought!! THANK YOU

Comment: Awesome. You saved me hours (I've already spent on other project with the same issue...)

Comment: The pleasure is mine! :)

Comment: @Cyupa Any ideas as to why it might be happening?